# Migration Endpoint - firewall settings - required open ports?

Tags: exchange, migration, office365

In a newly created hybrid Exchange 2013/Exchange Online environment, I am trying to migrate the first mailbox from on-premise to the cloud. For this, I open portal.office.com and navigate into ECP -> Recipients -> Migration. I Select "+" -> Migrate to Exchange Online, which opens a "new Migration Batch" window, lets me select the user to migrate and provide the Administrator credentials.

Then, the error I get is

> We couldn't detect your server settings. Please enter them. AutoDiscover failed with a configuration error: The migration service failed to detect the migration endpoint using the Autodiscover service. Consider using the Exchange Remote Connectivity Analyzer ‎(https://testexchangeconnectivity.com)‎ to diagnose the connectivity issues.

When I now enter the FQDN name or the IP address of our firewall router, I get the error(s)

> The connection to server autodiscover.ourdomain.com could not be established.
>   The connection to server 12.34.56.78 could not be established.

The router firewall only lets HTTPS (443) and SMTP (25) through to the Exchange server, so I guess we are just missing a port here.

Is this the correct assumption, and which port(s) could that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, the solution was to enabled "Basic" authentication on EWS virtual directory. Windows Integrated auth was already enabled.

Regards,
Laeeq Qazi

Answer (score 0):

25 & 443 should be all that you need, but it looks like your not getting a proper response.

First Hybrid Requirements are here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534377.aspx

On Exchange make sure the MRS Proxy service is enabled, it's disabled by default.

```
Set-WebServicesVirtualDirectory -Identity "YourServer\EWS (Default Web Site)" -MRSProxyEnabled $true
```

Make sure the Exchange Online IP's can send to your server over port 25. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn163583(v=exchg.150).aspx

Check your access from the Connectivity Analzyer
https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com

Run the Outlook Autodiscover and WebServices checks from the Exchange tab.  These should all pass, if not you may need to adjust your Firewall rules.